# SQL Server Agent stopped - Event ID 17052

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

I've had back to back Saturdays where our SQLServerAgent (Test Instance) has stopped with an Event ID of 17052. The times do differ as the initial week was 21:00 and last Saturday was 19:00. Having checked the event log, I get the below messages. After checking the SQL Server Agent job history, there were no job failures logged. The Server hosts multiple instance and all other services on the instance were not affected. Please can someone suggest what would cause SQL Server Agent to stop based on the below?

```
Select @@version
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64) Jul 3 2017 02:25:44 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Window Application Event Log:

```
Error Message No 1:
    The description for Event ID 17052 from source MSSQL$TEST cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

    If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

    The following information was included with the event: 

    SQLServerAgent Monitor: SQLServerAgent has terminated unexpectedly.

    the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

Error Message No 2:

    The description for Event ID 17052 from source MSSQL$TEST cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

    If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

    The following information was included with the event: 

    SQLServerAgent Monitor failed to restart SQLServerAgent after SQLServerAgent terminated unexpectedly (reason: SQLSCMControl() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.').

    the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

SQL Server Error Log:

```
    Date        11/08/2018 19:00:19
    Log     SQL Server Agent (Archive #1 - 11/08/2018 19:00:00)

    Message
    [165] ODBC Error: 0, COUNT field incorrect or syntax error [SQLSTATE 07002] (ConnExecuteCachableOp)


    Date        11/08/2018 19:00:09
    Log     SQL Server Agent (Archive #1 - 11/08/2018 19:00:00)

    Message
    [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]

    Date        11/08/2018 19:00:09
    Log     SQL Server Agent (Archive #1 - 11/08/2018 19:00:00)

    Message
    [298] SQLServer Error: 121, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]


    Date        11/08/2018 19:00:09
    Log     SQL Server Agent (Archive #1 - 11/08/2018 19:00:00)

    Message
    [298] SQLServer Error: 121, TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired. [SQLSTATE 08S01]
```

Comment: Can you please also add the output of `select @@version` in the question.

Comment: @Shanky Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64)   Jul  3 2017 02:25:44   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Is this standalone machine or cluster. Did you checked the service account of SQL server agent, that it has proper rights I can see the `access denied` message in the windows logs, is the account not locked ?

Comment: It's a stand alone machine. I've logged onto the server itself using the service account which SQL Server Agent uses and restarted the SQL Server Agent Service and that restarted without any issues

Comment: Seems like some AD policy issue to me. May be some rights are getting removed, triple check

Comment: Bit of a facepalm moment, I added the Service Account as a administrator on the server therefore it would obviously have access. I have now configured our monitoring software to restart in the event of the service stopping. Thanks for pointing out the permissions issue! Back to the initial failure... Is there anything glaringly obvious you can see that would have caused it to stop in the 1st place?

Comment: Nothing as such is obvious from the logs, you need to manually check the permission given to the service account before you added it in admin group. Or may be you need to search for similar logs